# Spring Expression Language validate String by contains() or Regex

Tags: xml, string, spring-el

I need to validate a String value by Regex
What I have is a way to use Spring Expression Language in a XML Document

```
component.previewImage.mime == 'image/png'
```

That's what I have at the moment. I want to achieve that the mime type string is validated if it contains **image**.
I'm not very affine with spring expression.

**Pseudo:**

```
component.previewImage.mime.contains('image')
```

is this possible? Or a way to use Regex Expression here?

**EDIT:**
Actual partwise working expression:

`newCMSComponent.detailText.values().^[!#empty(#this)] != null
                    AND (newCMSComponent.videoUrl != null OR (newCMSComponent.video != null AND newCMSComponent.video.mime == 'video/mp4'))
                    AND newCMSComponent.previewImage != null AND newCMSComponent.previewImage.mime matches 'image\/'"`

Be advised that the `newCMSComponent.previewImage.mime matches 'image\/'`does not work yet - that's the one I try to achieve.

Comment: Are you trying to perform an [XSD validation](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/example/)?

Comment: no - just using the above expression within a XML document. The point of this is to validate fields by their content.

Answer (score 0):

Since `contains()` is a method on `String`, you can use it as-is.

However, SpEL does support RegEx using the `matches` operator - see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operators-relational).

`"'5.00' matches '\^-?\\d+(\\.\\d{2})?$'"`

Comment: Sadly using `contains()` did not work. Will try the expression snippet

Comment: `"newCMSComponent.previewImage.mime matches 'image\/'"` that's the expression I use. It should match if any kind of `image/png`, `image/jpeg`, etc. occurs. Did I got something wrong?

Comment: `matches` needs a complete match, not a partial one; try `'image\/.*'`.